How do Queza, Augur of Agonies and Thought Reflection interact?
If I have Queza, Augur of Agonies and Thought Reflection on the battlefield, and draw a card would Queza's effect interrupt the second draw of Thought Reflection?
Does anything change if I also have Drogskol Reaver on the battlefield?

Card draws always happen one at a time:

121.2. Cards may only be drawn one at a time. If a player is instructed to draw multiple cards, that player performs that many individual card draws.

With Thought Reflection all "draw a card" instructions are effectively replaced with "Draw a card. Draw a card". After you draw your 2 cards, Queza, Augur of Agonies will have 2 triggers waiting to go on the stack. They will both go on the stack, and resolve 1 at a time. When the first one resolves, that will trigger Drogskol Reaver because you drew a card, so its trigger will go on the stack. This will continue indefinitely (until you either run out of cards to draw, or your opponent runs out of life, ending the game).
It works the same as if you didn't have Thought Reflection, except that there is an extra Queza trigger added to the stack each time, one which can never resolve due to the infinite loop always adding more triggers on top of it.

No, Queza's ability does not interrupt drawing two cards as instructed by Thought Reflection.
Thought Reflection's ability is a replacement effect. It modifies any instruction to draw a card with an instruction to draw two cards. Both card draws happen within the same spell, ability, or turn-based action as the original instruction to draw a card. Queza's ability is a triggered ability. It will only go on the stack after the original spell, ability, or turn-based action completes.
For a concrete example, consider resolving the spell Council's Deliberation, which instructs you to draw a card. The exact sequence of operations is as follows:

You start resolving Council's Deliberation. It instructs you to draw a card.
Thought Reflection replaces that with an instruction to draw two cards.
You draw the first card.
Queza's ability triggers.
You draw the second card.
Queza's ability triggers again.
You finish resolving Council's Deliberation.
You put both instances of Queza's ability on the stack, choosing the target opponent for each.
The first instance of Queza's ability resolves. The chosen target opponent for this instance loses 1 life and you gain 1 life.
The second instance of Queza's ability resolves. The chosen target opponent for this instance loses 1 life and you gain 1 life.

If you also control a Drogskol Reaver, its ability will trigger in step 9 when you gain 1 life. Its ability will go on the stack on top of the second instance of Queza's ability. When it resolves, it instructs you to draw a card, putting you in exactly the same situation as in step one of this sequence. This creates a loop where in every iteration, you draw two cards, you gain 1 life, and an opponent loses 1 life. This will continue until every opponent has 0 life and loses the game or you draw from an empty library and lose the game.

Because of Drogskol, the step 10 won't occur, right? After step 9, a new trigger will go on the stack before the second instance of Queza would resolve.

Drogskol Reaver is not relevant to the actual question "would Queza's effect interrupt the second draw of Thought reflection?"

"Thought Reflection replaces that with an instruction to draw two cards.
You draw the first card.
Queza's ability triggers." Technically, the triggers don't go onto the stack until the effect finishes resolving. In Dave Elden's terminology, the sequence is: you draw a card, the fairies write Queza's ability on the whiteboard, you draw the second card, the fairies write Queza's ability on the whiteboard, Council's Deliberation finishes resolving, the two Queza triggers go on the stack.

That's why I say that the ability triggers in steps 4 and 6, and that the triggers go on the stack in step 8.
